# How do people define the probability of absorption in terms of the size of the universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, absorption

Suppose we are in universe $M$ where we have only a photon $\gamma$ and an hydrogen atom $H$.
Let us define the probability of emission a photon by $P_1$ and the probability of absorption by $P_2$. Is clear that the $P_2$ will depend on the size of the universe $M$.

My question is when people define the probably of  absorption,  how do they define it in terms of the size of the universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absorption probability depends on the density. Thus you have to specify that the hydrogen atom is contained within a defined volume, $V$.

The photon mean free path is then $V/\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the absorption cross-section.

The photon travels $ct$ in time $t$, so the probability of absorption in that time will be
$$P_2 = 1 - \exp(-ct\sigma/V)$$

This would normally be used in a gas of many, many particles, but it assumes the probability of absorption is unaffected by the presence of other particles, so I think it works fine for 1 particle, randomly positioned within the box, so long as the photon is also in the box at all $t$.